# Make Images more vivid in Photoshop CS5

Tags: adobe-photoshop, image-editing

I am working on a project where I need to display nice flowers on a website. Now the flowers that I have got are not that well made, and making new ones is too much of a hassle.

I will display the image I have, and the image i want to create.
[image]

Now the image above is the one I have. You can see it is not that bright, and the colors of the flowers are not that vivid,bright, sharp.

[image]

Now here I have an image that is really sharp, vivid and good looking.

Anyone know a method to turn picture 1 into picture 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are probably new to photoshop I would suggest you use pre-made actions to get the desired effects. You will find many actions if you google for it but I'll give you a few link so that you get a head start.

> [70 of the best Photoshop actions](http://creativenerds.co.uk/freebies/70-of-the-best-photoshop-actions-for-enhancing-photos/)
>
> [60 actions for photo touch ups](http://designm.ag/resources/photoshop-actions-touchups/)
>
> [124 Free photoshop actions](http://www.visual-blast.com/photoshop/124-free-photoshop-actions/)

Getting the desired effect on your photo is a process of trial and error, as the actions can react differently to your photo than the illustrated effect shown as the demo.